# having multiple conf files for wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, wireless, wpa-supplicant

I can connect with no problem to my wpa wireless router using `wpa_supplicant`. Thing is I can't find out how to disconnect from it so I can connect to another device such as my phone's wifi, for instance. I have created a new conf file with "second wifi" information but the only way I have made it work is modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` file and reboot.

Comment: Umm ... You just add them into your file, no need for mulitple. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic specifically - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#WPA_supplicant

Comment: You can configure wifi with graphical tools (network manager) and from the command line (see the link I gave you). Not sure why you are editing system files ;)

Comment: well I edited that system file to enable my wifi configuration from boot.

Comment: ok, so how do I add a second essid to the config file using wpa_passphrase without overwrite the previous?

Comment: ok, so how do I add a second essid to the default config file using wpa_passphrase without overwrite the previous config in it?
I didn't read the whole page yet.. but I did read the specific part you showed me and priority isn't gonna work in my case. because I want to be able to switch between different connections I may have in my config file.. there have to be a way to tell wpa_supplicant to connect to one of the network set in the conf.
P.S reason why I don't have graphical tools is because I'm on a very minimal installation. I'm using a sorta low-end and old laptop.

Comment: " I didn't read the whole page yet." - read the page and then ask if you have a problem. Obviously you know the config to use as you are writing it and the page explains how to write your config.

Comment: You should use network manager to manage your configurations as NM overwrites your edits. You are doing this the hard way.

Comment: If you have a problem, update your question and post your configuration otherwise we really can not help.